# How to install VMware-Horizon-Client-5.4.0-1 on UBUNTU 18.04.4 LTS?

Tags: vmware

I have downloaded the ".bundel" file but I dont know what to do next. (VMware-Horizon-Client-5.4.0-15805449.x64.bundle) So far it only opens in a text editor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the downloaded file an executable...
On the command line, go to the Downloads folder - cd Downloads
chmod 777 (bundle file name)
ls -l (bundle file name) - should display rwxrwxrwx on the file
sudo ./(bundle file name) - should display Extracting VMware Installer...done.

then go to your 'start menu' and under Internet you should see VMware Horizon Client